# Batch containing 1 record(s) expired due to timeout while requesting metadata from brokers for test-0

Tags: apache-kafka

today a message prompt out when I try to send message to consumer console through producer console

```
[2016-11-02 15:12:58,168] ERROR Error when sending message to topic test with
key: null, value: 5 bytes with error:  
(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Batch containing 1 record(s) 
expired due to timeout while requesting metadata from brokers for test-0
```

Why is this happened? Is this consider as Kafka problem or Zookeeper problem?

Comment: Can you provide more information us with? kafka version? Kafka client version? Kafka server.config? Send command?

Comment: Kafka version 0.10.0.1

kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost_ip_address:9092 --topic test

broker.id=0
listeners = PLAINTEXT://localhost_ip_address:9092
port:9092

Comment: Can you update your post with server.config?

Comment: I had the exact same problem. were you able to find the root cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after I rebooted the whole server the problem is gone.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that client failed to retrieve metadata for test-0 from the kafka brokers.

Either make sure you are able to connect to the kafka brokers or check if 'advertised.listeners' is set if you are running kafka on IaaS machines.

Comment: Excuse me :) , what do you mean for "able to connect to the kafka brokers"?

Comment: Ensure client can talk to broker by specifying the right hostname and port information for brokers.

Comment: Do you mean the "server.properties" file?

Comment: Check listeners config in the server.properties file to make sure they are correct.

Comment: listeners = PLAINTEXT://**localhost_ip_address**:9092

I think that should be no problem

Comment: What do you specify for 'bootstrap.servers' in the client code?